# delete mutation is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm starting with graphql and I'm trying to remove a node at graphql but I not getting it.

Here is my resolver:

```
export default {
  Query: {
    allLinks: async (root, data, { mongo: { Links } }) =>
      Links.find({}).toArray()
  },
  Mutation: {
    createLink: async (root, data, { mongo: { Links }, user }) => {
      const newLink = Object.assign({ postedById: user && user._id }, data);
      const response = await Links.insert(newLink);
      return Object.assign({ id: response.insertedIds[0] }, newLink);
    },
    removeLink: async (root, { id }, { mongo: { Links }, user }) => {
      const newLink = Object.assign({ postedById: user && user._id });
      const response = await Links.remove(id);
      return Object.assign(response, newLink);
    },
    createUser: async (root, data, { mongo: { Users } }) => {
      const newUser = {
        name: data.name,
        email: data.authProvider.email.email,
        password: data.authProvider.email.password
      };
      const response = await Users.insert(newUser);
      return Object.assign({ id: response.insertedIds[0] }, newUser);
    },
    signinUser: async (root, data, { mongo: { Users } }) => {
      const user = await Users.findOne({ email: data.email.email });
      if (data.email.password === user.password) {
        return { token: `token-${user.email}`, user };
      }
    }
  },

  Link: {
    id: root => root._id || root.id,
    postedBy: async ({ postedById }, data, { dataloaders: { userLoader } }) => {
      return await userLoader.load(postedById);
    }
  },
  User: {
    id: root => root._id || root.id
  }
};
```

All mutations are working correctly less the removeLink.

When I run the removeLink mutation I got this error:

> MongoError: Wrong type for 'q'. Expected a object, got a string.

I know that something is wrong but I don't know what is.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's "not working correctly"? Is GraphQL returning any errors? if so, what? Also, the issue may be with the query you are submitting to the GraphQL endpoint or your type definitions... providing that information might help pin point the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to report the error. I will update my question

Answer (score 1):

You should use `deleteOne()` instead of `remove()` as `remove()` is deprecated. There's also not any reason to send back a link that you recently deleted.

Try something like this (don't know the rest of your code so I couldn't test it):

```
removeLink: async (root, { id }, { mongo: { Links }, user }) => {
  return await Links.deleteOne({ id });
},
```

If you would still like to return the deleted Link:

```
removeLink: async (root, { id }, { mongo: { Links }, user }) => {
  const newLink = Object.assign({ postedById: user && user._id });
  const response = await Links.deleteOne({ id });
  return Object.assign(response, newLink);
},
```

Comment: What information do you need? My schema? With your answer I got this error: "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Link.id."

Comment: In your schema you should not be expecting to send back a Link for the removeLink mutation. If you would still like to return the Link that was deleted, replace `Links.remove()` with my `Links.deleteOne()` into your code and see if it works. (I've edited my answer with more complete code if you'd like to take a look at that.)

Comment: I don't want to return the Link that was deleted, I just didn't know how to do this remotion. But what I return at my schema? 'removeLink(id: ID!): ?'

Comment: You can return whatever Mongo returns when an object is deleted. This should be a status, ok or not, and the number of items deleted (in your case 1).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with how you are using MongoDB and not GraphQL. If you look at [the docs for the `Collection.remove()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-that-match-a-condition) method, you'll see that you can pass it what they call a "query" where Mongo will remove all items that match the condition.

In your case, your query appears to be invalid. You are passing it the string `id` but you should be passing it the object `{ id: <some value> }`. I think that the line you want is:

```
const response = await Links.remove({ id: id});
```